# What is the difference between return or echo the view? return view is talking longer then echo view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

what is the best practice to load a view.

documentation is saying load view here https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views

following is my code:

```
 if (isset($results['status'])) {
           $error [] = $results['msg'];
           $request->session()->flash('message.level', 'danger');
           $request->session()->flash('message.content', $error);
 } else {
           if (view()->exists('import.device.results')) {
                  echo view('import.device.results', compact('results'));
                  exit;
           }
 }
```

when i use

> echo view('import.device.results', compact('results'));

it takes a second and when i use

> return view('import.device.results', compact('results'));

it takes like 10 seconds

my view file:

```
@extends('layouts_blue.master')
@section('content')
    <!--content-->

    <script language="JavaScript">
    </script>
    <div class="container content-body table-responsive" id="no-more-tables1">

        @if(session()->has('message.level'))
            <div class="alert alert-{{ session('message.level') }} import-device-error">
                <ul class="fa-ul">
                    @foreach (session('message.content') as $error)
                        <li>{!! $error !!}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        @endif

    </div>
    </div>
@stop
```

Comment: It should not be that  noticeable of difference in speed.  Profile your application and find out where it is hanging.

Comment: In Internet Explorer it shows my blank page for 3 seconds if i use return. echo works fine.

Comment: Like I said, use a profiler to find out why.   Could be a faulty session since session data is persisted in the middleware or a variety of things, none of which we'd be able to tell without debugging.

Comment: I found a solution.  the root cause is a profiler, when i disabled it, it starts working fine with the view too .thanks everyone

Comment: This is the best programmers community. I love it.

Comment: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar this is cause. When i disabled it, it starts working fine on IE.

Comment: I doubt it has anything to do with IE.  The debug bar is going to be retrieving and generating information for you at the end of the request so that makes sense, there must be something specific to your request that is causing it to work hard.

Comment: It works fine and never shows me blank page before loading the view file in any other browser excepts IE. Yes i am inserting data in 2 different tables and its CSV import, big big data files. I disabled my debugger and put back the return view, its working fine now. thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel performs a lot of necessary actions after it gets the response from your controller.  By exiting from your controller, you are terminating the request in the middle of its lifecycle:

- Terminable middleware will not be run.  Middleware in most frameworks can run before the request is sent to the controller and **after the response is received from the controller**.
- Terminating callbacks (registered in the application/container) will not be executed.
- Session may not be persisted.  Depending on the driver being used, session data may not be persisted until after the controller returns a response.
- All of your cookies and headers may not be sent.
- The response will not be automatically converted to a string or JSON.

Answer (score 2):

`return`  If called from within a function, the `return` statement immediately ends execution of the current function, and `returns` its the value of the function called. passing  a value to another function or variable.

`echo` outputs a value  one or more

`echo` prints the value so you can read it.

`return` returns the value to save in  variable.

In laravel same you can store view in variable by `return`.

In middleware `return` used to stop a execution or pass to the next function

In `return` u can return as you type like Json or object or many array with value.